# Set Default Compiler Warning Notifications for New Projects

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How can I set the default warning notifications so that all new projects will warn for implicit conversions, late bindings, and implicit types?  These options are available on the "Compile" tab, and are set to "None" by default:

[image]

I know it's probably in the project template -- the *.vbproj file -- but I can't figure out where.  I know how to make changes to built-in templates and install them into VS, so no need to explain that part.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  Needed to get rid of the `NoWarn` list -- i.e. change `<NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>` to `<NoWarn></NoWarn>` -- in two places within the .vbproj file.